# Does WiFiClient work on a Yún to send data over a certain IP and port to be received by a Python socket?

Tags: wifi, arduino-yun, communication, python

I haven't been able to get the example code from the page [WiFi:Client:connect()](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WiFiClientConnect) to work on my Arduino Yún. Is this not how I'm supposed to send data over WiFi to be read by something like a socket?

If not, how would I go about doing so? (This is the only solution I've found from the internet).

Answer (score 1):

No, that code is only for the WiFi shield.  For the Yun you need to look at the [Bridge](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/YunBridgeLibrary) library that is bundled with the IDE. It allows you to run commands and perform actions on the Linux based Atheros portion of the Yun which is what has access to the WiFi.